Identifying novel patterns in binary time series in R
I have a set of recorded observations about a binary animal behaviour ("open" or "closed") taken from ~200 individuals before and after an intervention. The data are structured as the state of the animal at each second of the test, so essentially a string of:



time
state




0
closed


1
closed


2
open


3
open


4
closed


5
closed



for each animal for 45 mins (2700 s). There are anywhere from 5-25 "close-open-close" events in each time series, of varying duration, inter-opening interval, etc.
I am hoping to extract novel patterns in this binary behaviour to determine if the patterns of the behaviour will change after my intervention. However, being a biologist, I am unsure where to start. I have looked into similar questions that recommend implementing an HMM, LSTM, or RNN to classify time series but it seems they are mostly preoccupied with forecasting, which I don't need to do, or using the time series to predict some other property, which while useful eventually, doesn't address my original idea, which is to define some "syllables" of animal open/closing behaviour and determine their frequency for each individual (somewhat similar to burst analysis of action potential firing, but with more diversity in the types of patterns to identify).
If anyone has any ideas as to how to begin to tackle this, if it's even possible, I would greatly appreciate it. My preference is for tools that can be implemented in R if possible.
Sample input:
library(tidyverse)
animal_1 <- tibble(
  id = c(a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a), 
  time = 0:9, 
  state = c("closed", "closed", "closed", "open", "open", "open", "open", "closed", "closed", "open")
)

